# Redirecting to a different site after submit/cancel on new, edit or display form

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, form, list-form

There is a well known feature in [SharePoint that allows you to specify in the URL where to go after a new/edit/display form is saved or closed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexma/archive/2006/06/17/635346.aspx) by using the Source param - e.g.

```
http://yoursite/Lists/yourlist/NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fyoursite%2FThankYou.aspx
```

However this only works if the Source destination is on the same server - any ideas about how to rediect to a different site - e.g. http://google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about bilding an application page and host in SharePoint, that onload does a `Response.Redirect` to your desired URL? Then you could just pass the url to this page as the Source parameter.

Comment: Like it - nice and pragmatic solution to this, thnaks!

Comment: You might even be able to pass in the url to redirect to from this page in a separate parameter, but I am not totally convinced that SharePoint will pass it on from the forms

Comment: I added it passed as a param to the Source param url (i.e. uri encoded twice) and it was passed through.